# cx_Oracle problem in AWS Lambda built using AWS CodeBuild

Tags: aws-lambda, cx-oracle, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to use cx_Oracle to connect to an RDS(Oracle) database from inside an AWS Lambda function (python3.7). Moreover, the Lambda function itself is automatically built from AWS CodeBuild using a buildspec.yml file. The CodeBuild itself runs by configuring AWS CodePipeline in such a way that whenever the repository where I put my code in (in this case AWS CodeCommit) is updated, it automatically builds the stuff.

Things that I have done:
1. I have an AWS Lambda function with code as follows.

```
    import cx_Oracle

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
      dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('www.host.com', '1521', 'dbname')
      connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user='user', password='password', dsn=dsn)

      cursor = connection.cursor()

      cursor.execute('select * from table_name')

      return cursor
```

2. Inside the buildspec.yml I have the following build commands.

```
    version: 0.2
    phases: 
      install:
        runtime-versions:
          python: 3.7
      commands:
        - pip install cx_Oracle -t ./ # to install cx_Oracle package in the same directory as the script
        - unzip instantclient-basic-linux*.zip -d /opt/oracle # I have downloaded the zip file beforehand

    <other code>
        -
```

3. I have also configured the template.yml of the Lambda function as follows

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
    Description: Making a test lambda function using codepipeline

    Resources:
       funcAuthorityReceive:
         Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
         Properties:
            FunctionName: testFunction
            Environment: 
            Variables:
              PATH: '/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_5:$PATH'
              LD_LIBRARY_PATH : '$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_5'
            Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
            MemorySize: 128
            Role: 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:role/role-for-lambda
            Runtime: python3.7
            CodeUri: ./
```

Here, everything runs smoothly and the Lambda function itself gets built, but when I run the lambda this error shows up:

```
"DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: \"libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future readers, the latest Oracle DB driver for Python doesn't necessarily need Instant Client, which makes deployment easier.  The driver got renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb, see https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use cx_Oracle to reach you oracle database, the moment you zip the lambda package (code and other dependencies), make sure you preserve the symlinks

[image: Oracle binaries]

```
zip --symlinks -r lambda.zip .
```

I haven't worked with codebuild, but I have build the lambda package in a linux server, soon I will be creating a build pipeline in Azure Devops.